# Reading a file from my desktop and printing each line from it

Tags: java

dear all here i have this code:

```
File file = new File("flowers_petal.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    while(in.hasNext()){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
```

I want to read from a file and print each line, but this code doesn't work because of some exceptions (throw exception??), how can i put it in a way that it would read from the flowers.txt file, which is on my desktop and will print each line from this file in the console?

Comment: You said "but this code doesn't work because of some exemption" You could add the exception you are getting to your question

Comment: Eclipse adds some, but they don't work and I'm not familiar with exemptions at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.. Full code sample. Assuming you put you file in C:\some_folder

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReader {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    File file = new File("C:\\some_folder\\flowers_petal.txt");
    Scanner in;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(file);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recheck your code

```
File file = new File("flowers_petal.txt"); // This is not your desktop location.. You are probably getting FileNotFoundException. Put Absolute path of the file here..
      while(in.hasNext()){  // checking if a "space" delimited String exists in the file
                String line = in.nextLine(); // reading an entire line (of space delimited Strings)
                System.out.println(line);
```

SideNote : use FileReader + BufferedReader for "reading" a file. Use Scanner for parsing a file..

Comment: then shall i add the path to the file, instead of the name? But then if it still in "" then it might not point to the file anyway. How do i point to a file stored on my PC?

Comment: use "C:\\Users\\yourName\\Desktop\\yourFile.txt"

Comment: When i use this: File file = new File("C:/Users/elenanikolova/Desktop/flowers_petal.txt"); and if i want to print the file: System.out.println(file); i get :C:/Users/elenanikolova/Desktop/flowers_petal.txt and not the con taint of the file flower_petals.txt

Comment: You are printing the fileName . Not file contents by calling  System.out.println(file);

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for the wrong condition, you need to check for `hasNextline()` instead of `hasNext()`. So the loop will be

```
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    String line = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: I changed it, still doesn't work, I don't know how to wrap it up in the main method and do include exceptions…then it might work

Answer (score 0):

Consider these 2 points :

1. the current location you are giving in your file is not valid (*if
   your .java (source) file is not on Desktop*), so give the full path
   for your file.
2. the [`new Scanner(File file)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) throws `FileNotFoundException`, so you have to put the code in `try-catch` block or just use `throws`.

Your code may look like this :

```
try {
    File file = new File("path_to_Desktop/flowers_petal.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    while(in.hasNextLine()){
       String line = in.nextLine();
       System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //If your java file is in the same directory as the text file
    //then no need to specify the full path ,You can just write
    //File file = new File("flowers_petal.txt");

    File file = new File("/home/ashok/Desktop/flowers_petal.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    while(in.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    }
    in.close();
}
```

**NOTE :I am using linux ,If you are using windows your desktop path would be different**

Answer (score 0):

Try this................

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt")))
    {

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
}
```

give your exact path in the FileReader("exact path must be here...")

source: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Comment: Tnx, i will try this also, as i want to see how the FileReader works, tnx!